# Notice: Undefined index: qnews in

Tags: php, indexing, undefined

```
<?php
    _setView ( __FILE__ );
    _setTitle ( $langArray ['add'].' '.$langArray['qnews'] );
```

Please give me some instruction for fix this problem:

> Notice: Undefined index: qnews in
>   /home/market/apps/qnews/admin/add.php on line 3

Comment: Check whether your `$langArray` has an index of `qnews`

Comment: Never mind, learn php a bit more

Comment: but a little instruction?

Comment: Use `var_dump($langArray)`.

Comment: tnks, but search it in same php

Comment: increase error: array(804) { ["username"]=> string(8) "Username" ["password"]=> string(8) "Password" ["email"]=> string(6) "E-mail" ["remember_me"]=> string(11) "Remember me" ["login"]=> string(5) "Login" ["logout"]=> string(6) "Logout" ["welcome"]=> string(7) ....